# Why does recreating a yarn lock file cause type errors?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, yarnpkg

I have a React/Redux project using typescript and yarn to manage the application's dependencies. Whenever I delete the node modules folder, the yarn lock file and recreate the node modules folder and the lock file with yarn install, the entire application breaks with type errors.

Is it bad practice to delete a yarn lock file and recreate it with a yarn install?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the integrity of your `yarn.lock` file using

```
 yarn check
 yarn check --integrity
```

If you are still having issues

```
yarn clean
```

"Once you run yarn clean, Yarn will create a `.yarnclean` file that should be added to version control. Cleaning is then automatically done as part of yarn install (or simply yarn) and yarn add."

Its not bad practice to use yarn tools to clean or create new file.